# Cannot convert to NSDate from string

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Below are the  date strings received from the server

```
2012-07-05T11:18:00-04:00 or 2012-12-05T10:26:00-05:00
```

As far as I know 04:00 and 05:00 are the numeric time zone offset. They may be +04:00 or +05:00

**My question is:**

How can I set `setDateFormat` for `NSDateFormat` if the time zone offset are varied right now?

Please advice me on this issue if you have any clues

All comments are welcomed here.

Edited:
If i do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *format                 =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'-'04':'00"];
```

It won't work with if the date string is `2012-12-05T10:26:00-05:00`.Therefore I am looking for a general format so that it can work for both cases

Comment: NSData or NSDate?  Please provide a code sample of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, I was beginning to wonder what had happened to the daily NSDateFormatter question -- haven't seen it for several days.

Comment: (There is a standard problem that when handling a timestamp with the timezone offset, you must first remove the ":" before trying to parse it with NSDateFormatter.)

Comment: i dont think we need to remove the : before parsing it. It worked fine with :

Comment: If you want to parse the timezone, you need to remove the ":".  The parse strings you were using did not parse the timezone but ignored it, meaning you lose the hour information in the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"` or perhaps `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ"` as the setDateFormat: argument.

Comment: 'ZZZ' parses the time zone.  See 'Apple Data Formatting Guide :: Date Formatters'

Comment: (After removing the ":" from the timezone.)

Comment: should we have @"yyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss ZZZ"

Comment: @ttran -- The single quotes are generally not required to set apart non-alphanumeric literals.

Comment: @HotLicks : you mentioned ":" should be removed, which one the first or the second or the third or all of them

Comment: See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns You do need to remove the final ':'.

Comment: Yep, the final one -- in the timezone offset field.